# How to customize shortcut keys on Git Bash Terminal (Windows 10)

Tags: bash, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, git

How can I customize shortcut keys on Git Bash Terminal?

When I use the Option -> Keys, it only allows to turn on or off the features. What I want is to change the key combinations. Here are my settings:

[image: Git Bash Terminal]

For your information, the combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> doesn't work for my specific laptop. When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>, this is what I get:

[image: Shift + Insert]

Comment: Which of the [Bash Shortcuts](https://gist.github.com/tuxfight3r/60051ac67c5f0445efee) you wish to customize?

Comment: @harrymc It's the copy - paste shortcuts that I want to customize.

Comment: What would you like them to be? The usual Ctrl-C/V cannot be used here.

Comment: I want to make them to be Ctrl + Shift + C / Ctrl + Shift + V.

Comment: How would I replace/override the CTRL-C/V commands and use a different key for those if I prefer to change that instead of copy/paste?

Answer (score 7):

By default

> Options > Keys > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>letter shortcuts</kbd> is disabled(unchecked).

To use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut for Paste, enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>letter shortcuts</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable  Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts, by right clicking on your window header and selecting options. You will find the setting there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key + the F-key to get <kbd>Insert</kbd>!

First off, the reason you get a `2~` when you try to paste with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> is because you are accidentally pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F-key</kbd> (such as <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>), instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

I bet your <kbd>Insert</kbd> key is on an F-key, such as <kbd>F10</kbd>, for instance, like mine is on my HP Elitebook laptop. Use the <kbd>Fn</kbd> function key to make it the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key. For me, I must press **<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>** in order to get <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

You can also enable Linux-terminal-like copy and paste using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>, which is much easier and faster to use in my opinion. Here's how:

### How to enable Linux-terminal-like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd> Copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>V</kbd> Paste in Git Bash (for Windows)

As other answers have said:

Right-click on the background in Git Bash --> "Options..." --> Keys --> check the box for "Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts" --> Apply --> Save. Here is a screenshot of that:

[image]

Now, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd> to copy from the Git Bash terminal, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into it! This is how the terminal works in Linux too.

**Secondary clipboard:**

Lastly, to copy/paste *within the terminal itself only* (meaning: copy from within the Git Bash terminal to within the Git Bash terminal), you can use your secondary copy/paste clipboard: **copy simply by highlighting the text with your mouse,** and **paste by center-clicking (click with the scroll wheel) on your mouse.**

On Linux Ubuntu, this works anywhere in Linux--in any program and between any program to any program, but on Windows, it just works within the Git Bash terminal.